# Method called within thread executes in unexpected order (C# .net)

Tags: c#, multithreading, program-flow

seeking general help in understanding this program flow:
In a windows forms application why is it that when I call a method within a new thread that the thread doesn't wait for the method to complete before continuing execution?

Are methods called within a thread executed asynchronously by default? (I would expect the program to block until the method is complete without having to use the Thread.Sleep line below).  The comment on the "Thread.Sleep" line below may help to clarify my question further.  - Thank you!

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Call doStuff in new thread:
        System.Threading.Thread myThread;
        myThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(doStuff));
        myThread.Start();
    }

    private void doStuff()
    {
        //Instantiate external class used for threadSafe interaction with UI objects:
        ThreadSafeCalls tsc = new ThreadSafeCalls();
        int indx_firstColumn = 0;

        //Loop 3 times, add a row, and add value of "lastRowAdded" to column1 cell.
        for (int a = 0; a < 3; a += 1)
        {
            tsc.AddGridRow(dataGridView1); //Call method to add a row to gridview:
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // Why does the execution of the line above go all crazy if I don't pause here? It's executing on the same thread, shouldn't it be synchronous? 
            tsc.AddGridCellData(dataGridView1,indx_firstColumn, tsc.lastRowAdded,tsc.lastRowAdded.ToString()); //Add value of "lastRowAdded" (for visual debugging)
        }
```

Content of the "ThreadSafeCalls" class:

```
        public int lastRowAdded = -999;

    public void AddGridRow(DataGridView gv)
    {
        if (gv.InvokeRequired)
        {
            gv.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () 
            {
                lastRowAdded = gv.Rows.Add();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            lastRowAdded = gv.Rows.Add();
        }
    }

    public void AddGridCellData(DataGridView gv, int column, int rowID, string value)
    {
        //Thread safe:
            if (gv.InvokeRequired)
            {
                gv.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { gv.Rows[rowID].Cells[column].Value = value + " "; });
            }
            else
            {
                gv.Rows[rowID].Cells[column].Value = value;
            }
    }
```

Comment: You really need to provide us with a [mcve]. I've tried to replicate your issue, but can't. Something might be going on in code we can't see.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Edit:** It's not exactly clear what you mean by "go all crazy", but after staring at the code for an unhealthy amount of time I realized there's a race window that manifests itself in the loop when sleeping isn't used. I ran a stripped version of this many times to confirm. Apologies for the long edit, but without details it's difficult to understand the problem.

```
//Loop 3 times, add a row, and add value of "lastRowAdded" to column1 cell.
for (int a = 0; a < 3; a += 1)
{
    tsc.AddGridRow(dataGridView1); //Call method to add a row to gridview:
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // Why does the execution of the line above go all crazy if I don't pause here? It's executing on the same thread, shouldn't it be synchronous? 
    tsc.AddGridCellData(dataGridView1,indx_firstColumn, tsc.lastRowAdded,tsc.lastRowAdded.ToString()); //Add value of "lastRowAdded" (for visual debugging)
}
```

Breaking it down:

1. Schedule the addition of a row and update of `lastRowAdded` on the UI thread.
2. Sleep for 1s. Leaving this out causes the race to manifest.
3. Pass the value and string equivalent of `lastRowAdded` as `myThread` remembers it, scheduling the cell to be updated on the UI thread.
4. Repeat 3 times.

The reason you're experiencing this is due to [caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache). Essentially when you leave out the sleep `myThread` sees a stale version of `lastRowAdded`, which then passes a stale copy to `AddGridCellData`. This stale value propagates to the UI thread, often resulting in -999 or some other incorrect row index. You should be getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException` sometimes, but not always. Sleeping happens to give the UI thread enough time to write its cached values back to main memory, where `myThread` then reads the updated value. It appears to work correctly on some runs and incorrectly on others depending on which cores the OS schedules the threads on.

To fix this you need to remove the sleep and synchronize access to all mutable data inside `ThreadSafeCalls`. The simplest way to do that is to use a lock.

i.e.

Loop implementation:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 3; a += 1)
{
    tsc.AddGridRow(dataGridView1);
    tsc.AddGridCellData(dataGridView1, indx_firstColumn);
}
```

TSC implementation:

```
class ThreadSafeCalls
{
    private object syncObject = new object();
    private int lastRowAdded = -999;

    public int LastRowAdded
    {
        get {
            lock (syncObject) {
                return lastRowAdded;
            }
        }
        set {
            lock (syncObject) {
                lastRowAdded = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddGridRow(DataGridView gv)
    {
        if (gv.InvokeRequired) {
            gv.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () {
                LastRowAdded = gv.Rows.Add();
            });
        }
        else {
            LastRowAdded = gv.Rows.Add();
        }
    }
    public void AddGridCellData(DataGridView gv, int column)
    {
        if (gv.InvokeRequired) {
            gv.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () {
                var lastRow = LastRowAdded;
                gv.Rows[lastRow].Cells[column].Value = lastRow + " "; 
            });
        } else {
            var lastRow = LastRowAdded;
            gv.Rows[lastRow].Cells[column].Value = lastRow + " ";
        }
    }
}
```

**Original Answer:**

> Are methods called within a thread executed asynchronously by default?

Yes when referring to execution of the `ThreadStart` target method with respect to the creating thread; that's the point of threads. You use additional threads to do things like load in the background or additional processing without blocking your main thread.

> (I would expect the program to block until the method is complete
>   without having to use the Thread.Sleep line below).

`BeginInvoke` adds a method to the UI thread scheduler to be invoked later **on the UI thread** when it's done with whatever it was doing prior(i.e. handling OS events, executing a method scheduled before the one you're adding). This is deferred execution, and returns as soon as it's scheduled, that's why it's not blocking. The reason execution is deferred to the UI thread is that most of the UI framework isn't thread-safe. Multiple threads modifying the UI leads to data races, creating all sorts of problems.

On a side note, you should really avoid creating threads in response to user input. Threads are expensive resources that should be created as soon as possible(ideally at initialization time). In your example you're creating a thread every time your button is clicked, which is very slow.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. **Methods called within a thread executed _synchronously_**.

Comment: Perhaps the wording threw you off. Threads are synchronous when referring to execution within the same thread, but with respect to other threads they're ***asynchronous***.

Comment: Correct. The OP is asking about **"Methods called within a thread"** so the answer is that the calls are **synchronous**.

Comment: Yes, but by using BeginInvoke another thread(the UI thread) is introduced into the mix, inadvertently making the synchronous question an asynchronous one. The framework itself, and likely other parts of the OP's codebase are also dispatching to the UI thread. My answer isn't wrong it just doesn't entirely explain the problem.

Comment: Yes, but the `BeginInvoke` is calling back to the UI thread. It doesn't change the order of the calls from the thread that the OP is creating. Your opening statement in your answer isn't correct.

Comment: Right, we agree on that. The OP was/is confused about blocking in the context of the question and stated "I would expect the program to block until the method is complete without having to use the Thread.Sleep line below". My answer was intended to explain ***why*** it doesn't block, but not the unexplained "go all crazy" behavior. I'll attempt to clarify in the answer.

Comment: Thank you Koby, that was a perfectly detailed answer.  (Sorry for anyone who couldn't replicate it using my sample code, I thought I had enough code in there without being overly complex).  "Intermittent indexOutOfRangeException" would have been a better explanation than "go all crazy". :)

Comment: @jWolf I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

From search results:

`Control.BeginInvoke Method (System.Windows.Forms)`

Executes a delegate asynchronously on the thread that the control's underlying handle was created on. Executes the specified delegate asynchronously on the thread

Source: [Control.BeginInvoke Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx) on msdn.